# How do we feel temperature?

Tags: senses, heat

Recently I watched a Youtube Video by
[Veritasium](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vqDbMEdLiCs)

He said we are actually feeling the rate of heat transfer, not the temperature.

But how do we feel temperature?
How is feeling temperature different from feeling heat and heat transfer?

Comment: Welcome to the Biology Stack Exchange. Please take the [tour] and carefully read through the [help] to learn more about the site, including [what is on-topic](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [what is not](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), and how to [ask a good question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Mesentery - although your links are highly useful, new users are likely overwhelmed and do not know what you are after. If you have certain critiques, please make them explicit, especially to new users. Posting a standard welcome message with all sort of links within the site may have its merits, but is arguably not the best thing to do. Other users have started doing that and have eventually been discouraged. Specific pointers are, imho, better.

Comment: @AliceD I have seen that this user has not got the informed badge. I just want him to guide him about how this site works. So, if he/she asks further any questions, they are also on-topic on the site.

Comment: @Mesentery - that is awesome. Mentioning this explicitly will help this new user even more I think. Thanks for all your good work here and for your efforts. I'm not aiming to criticize, just trying to be constructive. Cheers.

Comment: After all that being said, a summary would be - did you try finding an answer? *'Provide details. Share your research'*, else it is likely to be closed as a low effort question. I'm voting as one.

Comment: use google.  "nerve temperature response" = https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermoreceptor afaik they have different ranges for different precision/speed of response. the topic takes 30 40 minutes of going on good pages to be knowledgeable on for the rest of your life, and one day you can use all your knowledges as a combined power of generalist science knowledge. research is good.